# Show that $f \in L^{1}(X)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(E_{n}) < \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$  a finite measure space. Also let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $$E_{n}=\lbrace x \in X \: | \: |f(x)| \in [n,n-1) \rbrace$$. Show that $f \in L^{1}(X)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(E_{n}) < \infty$. More generally  $f \in L^{p}(X)$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p} \mu(E_{n}) < \infty$. I have been trying to solve this problem since a couple of days but being honest I, frustrated since I can came with any idea or proof of this. So far I have been checking the analogue problem here

[Prove that $f$ is integrable if and only if $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \mu(\{x \in X : f(x) \ge n\}) < \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387040/prove-that-f-is-integrable-if-and-only-if-sum-infty-n-1-mu-x-in-x-f)

but still dont understand the proofs there as well there are other hypothesis going on there. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the proof is exactly the same as for the other statement (in fact, the sums in question are equal). I'm assuming, by the way, that you meant $E_n=[n-1,n)$.

Basically, $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{E_n} f,$ and clealy $1_{E_n} f$ lies between $n-1$ and $n$ when it's not equal to $0$. Hence, $1_{E_n}f\leq 1_{E_n}n$ and $1_{E_n}f \geq 1_{E_n} (n-1),$ and we get, by Monotone Convergence, that

$$
\int f\textrm{d}\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f 1_{E_n}\textrm{d}\mu\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(E_n)
$$
and similarly,

$$
\int f\textrm{d}\mu\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)\mu(E_n)\geq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \mu(E_n)\right) -\mu(X),
$$

where we've used that $\mu(X)<\infty$ and that the $E_n$ are disjoint.

The statement follows. The general $L^p$ argument is similar.

Comment: Thanks! But where the inequality $
\int f\textrm{d}\mu\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)\mu(E_n)\geq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \mu(E_n)\right) -\mu(X),
$ comes from ? :/ @WoolierThanThou

Comment: It's more or less exactly the same computation as above. If this confuses you, it's probably a very good exercise to try to fill in the steps yourself.