# Prove that if $f$ is integrable then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{x: |f(x)| > n \}) = 0$.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that if $\int |f| d\mu < \infty$  then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{x: |f(x)| > n \}) = 0$.

I have found [a similar looking question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387040/prove-that-f-is-integrable-if-and-only-if-sum-infty-n-1-mu-x-in-x-f) but could not get grasp of accepted answer.

My general idea was that because f is integrable, the set of all x where $f(x) = \infty$ has measure 0 and in consequence this limit must go to 0 too, but I could not formalize it correctly.

Comment: Chebyshevs inequality

Comment: I think you need $\int |f| d \mu < \infty$, that is you need full integrability.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг you're right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $E_n:= \{|f| \geq n\}$. Note that

$$\mu(E_n) = \mu\{|f|/n \geq 1\} = \int I_{\{|f|^p /n \geq 1\}}d \mu \leq \int |f|/n d \mu = 1/n \int|f| d \mu \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$$

since $$\int|f| d \mu < \infty$$

and where we used the trivial inequality

$$I_{\{|f| /n \geq 1\}} \leq|f|/n$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you denote $A_n=\{x: |f(x)| > n \}$, then you can write:

$$ \int \vert f\vert d\mu= \int_{A_n^c}\vert f\vert d\mu+ \int_{A_n}\vert f\vert d\mu $$

Assume that $\mu(A_n)\not\rightarrow 0$, and use monotonicity of the integral to conclude that for some $\epsilon>0$:

$$ \int \vert f\vert d\mu\geq \epsilon_0 \cdot n_k \rightarrow \infty $$

Which must be a contradiction since $ \int \vert f\vert d\mu$ is finite.

By the way $\mu(A_n)$ can not tend to infinity while $\vert f\vert$ is always finite, so that sort of argument won't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the contradiction?